# FFMPEG build with cmake on windows

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, cmake

I 'm trying to build project with ffmpeg libraries by Cmake.
ffmpeg is installed correctly. When i type `ffmpeg` on cmd i have:

```
ffmpeg version N-99488-gbc43588a71 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-debug --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavcodec     58.110.100 / 58.110.100
  libavformat    58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.102 / 58. 11.102
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

But when i try to build my project i get:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
-- Using Win32 for window creation
-- Checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   No package 'libavcodec' found
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:545 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:733 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  lib/FFmpeg/CMakeLists.txt:5 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/mswar/Desktop/App Video/video-app/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/mswar/Desktop/App Video/video-app/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have no idea what's going on. On path : C:\Users\mswar\Desktop\App Video\video-app i have **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
project(video-app C CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)



add_subdirectory(lib/glfw)
add_subdirectory(lib/FFmpeg)
add_definitions(-DGL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION)

if(WIN32)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
    "-lglu32 -lopengl32")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-std=gnu99 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -mwindows")
else()
list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS"-lGL -lGLU -lX11")
endif()

list(APPEND SOURCES
src/main.cpp
src/load_frame.cpp
)
add_executable(video-app ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(video-app FFmpeg glfw ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

In : `C:\Users\mswar\Desktop\App Video\video-app\lib\FFmpeg` i have CMakeLists.txt file with content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(FFmpeg)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(AVCODEC       REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavcodec)
pkg_check_modules(AVFORMAT      REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavformat)
pkg_check_modules(AVFILTER      REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavfilter)
pkg_check_modules(AVDEVICE      REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice)
pkg_check_modules(AVUTIL        REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavutil)
pkg_check_modules(ASWRESAMPLE   REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswresample)
pkg_check_modules(SWSCALE       REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswrescale)


add_library(FFmpeg INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
target_include_directories(FFmpeg INTERFACE
${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${AVFILTER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_options(FFmpeg INTERFACE
${AVCODEC_LDFLAGS}
${AVFORMAT_LDFLAGS}
${AVFILTER_LDFLAGS}
${AVDEVICE_LDFLAGS}
${AVUTIL_LDFLAGS}
${SWRESAMPLE_LDFLAGS}
${SWSCALE_LDFLAGS}
)
```

Kindly please help!

Comment: "I have no idea what's going on." - According to the log, the file `lib/FFmpeg/CMakeLists.txt:5` calls `pkg_check_modules` which looks for `libavcodec` module(library) using pkg-config utility. But it cannot find that module. BTW, you don't show the content of file `lib/FFmpeg/CMakeLists.txt`, where you have obtained this file?

Comment: Yes, you're right. On path: C:\Users\mswar\Desktop\App Video\video-app\lib\FFmpeg i have CMakeLists.txt. I edited post